# Block access to website from router(using its IP adress)

Tags: networking, router, ubuntu-18.04, telnet, dig

I'm trying to block access to a website (e.g site.com), to do so I used `dig site.com` to get the site's IP adress (I'm on Ubuntu). The result will be something like this:

```
site.com.       10000   IN  A   101.53.182.181`
```

Then mapped new IP ( localhost ) to the domain name 'site.com' on `/etc/hosts`, as the following:

```
127.0.0.1       site.com
```

That will do the thing for my local machine, but not for the whole network's devices.
Also tried to configure from the router using `telnet 192.168.1.1` but I lost it, I don't know how to do it.

How can I manage to block traffic from that particular site? Is there anyway to block access to websites using their IP address?

**PS:** I tried the classic way to block the site using its domain name (e.g site.com), but it doesn't really 'block the site', I can still access it by searching the website on Google.

Answer (score 3):

You can try accessing your router's web interface. Make sure to set your computer's (laptop's) IP address manually to `192.168.1.2`, subnet mask to `255.255.255.0` and then gateway to `192.168.1.1` for the computer's `Eth0` interface. I suggest to use the wired interface instead of **WLAN** or **WiFi**. Then, access the router on a web browser using `192.168.1.1`.

In your router's settings page, look for the following:

- Block Sites
- Access Restrictions
- Security
- Advanced

or something similar to the mentioned categories above. This may depend on the settings, so I advise to refer to your router's manual. Once you find the setting, indicate the domain/s or IP address (via dig) that you want to block, then apply the settings or changes that you have made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, idk why i didn't thought of using IP adress instead of domain name lol, however i still can acces to that site on my phone. I'am Trying to figure out how to set standard ACL to my router interface to deny any request coming from my local network toward that particular site.

Comment: This will depend on your router's interface. It can be configured via GUI, or CLI. You can check the model number of your router, then look or check for its manual or online documentation for a more precise guide.